# jquery change style on click (context = bootstrap)

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have this text field that is too large to show, but you want a button that will display the rest:

```
<div class="span4" >
    some description..
    <div class="hidden-text" style="display:none">
        rest of description<br/>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="btn" id="readmore"><i class="icon-chevron-up"></i> Read more</a>
    <script>
    $("#readmore").click(function(){
        $('#hidden-text').attr('style', '');
    });
    </script>
</div>
```

Why does this not work and how should it be done?

EDIT:

Thanks for the demo, unfortunately I can't replicate it

```
<div class="span4" >
    some description..
    <style>
    .hidden-text {
        display:none;
    }​
    </style>
    <p class="hidden-text">rest of description<br/></p>
    <br/><br/>
    <a href="#" class="btn" id="readmore"><i class="icon-chevron-down"></i> Read more</a>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.readmore').on('click', function(){
            $('.hidden-text').slideDown('slow');
            });
    });​
    </script>
</div>
```

I don't see what is so different from the demo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're referencing jQuery on your page.

Your code isn't working because you're trying to take the style off an item with the id of hidden-text yet your text has a CLASS of hidden-text. You want this:

```
<div class="span4" >
some description..
<div class="hidden-text" style="display:none">
    rest of description<br/>
</div>
<a href="#" class="btn" id="readmore"><i class="icon-chevron-up"></i> Read more</a>
<script>
$("#readmore").click(function(){
    $('.hidden-text').attr('style', '');
});
</script>
</div>
```

notice the . in the attribute line where you had # and honestly the show is a better solution

```
$('.hidden-text').show();
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing

```
$('#hidden-text').attr('style', '');
```

to remove the `display:none`, just do

```
$('#hidden-text').show()
```

Or, if you want it to slide down, you could even do

```
$('#hidden-text').slideDown();
```

Reference:

[jQuery .show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/)
[jQuery .slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/)

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FP3kj/1/)

Comment: You're missing the fact that he's referencing an ID that doesn't exist.